# Concisely initializing a vector of Strings

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a vector of `String`s to test arg parsing (since this is what `std::env::args()` returns) but struggling with how to do this concisely.

What I want:

```
let test_args = vec!["-w", "60", "arg"]; // should array of Strings
let expected_results = my_arg_parser(test_args);
```

This obviously doesn't work because the vectors contents are all `&str`s.

Using `String::from` but works but doesn't scale well and is ugly :)

```
let args = vec![String::from("-w"), String::from("60"), String::from("args")];
```

I could map over the references and return string objects, but this seems very verbose:

```
let args = vec!["-w", "60", "args"].iter().map(|x| x.to_string()).collect::<Vec<String>>();
```

Should I just create a helper function to do the conversion, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the `to_string()` method directly on the literals:

```
let test_args = vec!["-w".to_string(), "60".to_string(), "arg".to_string()];
```

Otherwise a macro to do this would be as simple as:

```
macro_rules! vec_of_strings {
    ($($x:expr),*) => (vec![$($x.to_string()),*]);
}
```

[See play.rust.org example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bfb5144953af92f8ff8a2ec9b5861c93&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Thanks for the macro, that's quite nice! While `to_string` is slightly shorter than `String::From`, is there any advantage in using it over `String::from`?

Comment: It actually is equivalent: have a look at the `to_string` implementation https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/collections/up/src/libcollections/string.rs.html#1768-1774

Answer (score 18):

JDemler already provided a nice answer. I have two additional things to say:

First, you can also use `into()` instead of `to_string()` for all elements but the first. This is slightly shorter and also equivalent to `to_string()`/`String::from()`. Looks like this:

```
vec!["a".to_string(), "b".into(), "c".into()];
```

---

Second, you might want to redesign your arg parsing. I will assume here that you won't mutate the `String`s you get from `env::args()`. I imagine your current function to look like:

```
fn parse_args(args: &[String]) -> SomeResult { ... }
```

But you can make that function more generic by not accepting `String`s but [`AsRef<str>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html). It would look like this:

```
fn parse_args<T: AsRef<str>>(args: &[T]) -> SomeResult { ... }
```

In the documentation you can see that `String` as well as `str` itself implement that trait. Therefore you can pass a `&[String]` *and* a `&[&str]` into your function. Awesome, eh?

---

In similar fashion, if you want to accept anything that can be converted into an owned `String`, you can accept `<T: Into<String>>` and if you want to return either a `String` or an `&str`, you can use [`Cow`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html). You can read more about that [here](http://hermanradtke.com/2015/05/29/creating-a-rust-function-that-returns-string-or-str.html) and [here](http://hermanradtke.com/2015/05/06/creating-a-rust-function-that-accepts-string-or-str.html).

Apart from all that: there are plenty of good CLI-Arg parsers out there ([`clap-rs`](https://github.com/kbknapp/clap-rs), [`docopt-rs`](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.rs), ...), so you might not need to write your own.

Answer (score 12):

I agree that [Lukas Kalbertodt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38185570/155423) is the best — use generics to accept anything that can look like a slice of strings.

However, you can clean up the `map` version a little bit:

1. There's no need to allocate a vector for the initial set of strings.
2. There's no need to use the complete type (`Vec<String>`); you could specify just the collection (`Vec<_>`). If you pass the result to a function that only accepts a `Vec<String>`, then you don't need any explicit types at all; it can be completely inferred.
3. You can use a slightly shorter `s.into()` in the `map`.

---

```
fn do_stuff_with_args(args: Vec<String>) { println!("{}", args.len()) }

fn main() {
    let args = ["-w", "60", "args"].iter().map(|&s| s.into()).collect();
    do_stuff_with_args(args);
}
```

Comment: You can actually simplify this even further with using `into_iter` and `.map(str::to_owned)`